# Error while installing Omnet++ on Ubuntu 16.04 : Cannot find osgEarth

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, omnet++

I followed the installation guide and installed all the packages mentioned. However, I end up with this error message while running ./configure

```
checking for osgEarth with CFLAGS=" -fPIC  -fno-stack-protector  " LIBS="  -losgEarth -losgEarthUtil"... no
configure: error: Cannot find osgEarth 2.7 or later. Set WITH_OSGEARTH=no in configure.user to disable this feature or install an up to date version of osgEarth.
```

Here is a link to my config.log file : [config.log](https://pastebin.com/JzhsCZu3)

Comment: Have you installed `openscenegraph-plugin-osgearth` and `libosgearth-dev`?

Comment: Yes, I did install them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the `libgeos-dev` package, and then editing the `configure.user` file in my OMnet++ source directory solved my problem.

`$ sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev`

Change the line `#OSGEARTH_LIBS=` to this: 
`OSGEARTH_LIBS=" -losgEarth -losgEarthUtil -lgeos_c "` 
Make sure to remove the # in the beginning.

Now run:

```
$ . setenv
$ ./configure
```

And it should work..

Others have also faced this problem before and have the fix mentioned here solved their issues:
http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/boards/1/topics/4621
https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/changeset/11363

Answered by Attila Török on the omnetpp google group (omnetpp@googlegroups.com)

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot find osgEarth 2.7 or later

`osgearth 2.7` for Ubuntu 16.04 → https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa →

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libosgearth-dev         // you get "2.7"

   // All prerequisites :
sudo apt install g++ libxml2-dev libosgearth-dev bison flex clang swig libqt5opengl5-dev qt5-qmake openjdk-8-jre libopenmpi-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS does not contain package for oegearth version 2.7. The solution is adding ppa that contains v2.7. That solves the problem.